# Specify Column For Tablesorter Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, tablesorter

I have the tablesorter working which allows me to type in each column heading the text to sort the table below.  I have the datapicker attached to it but it is currently set to the wrong column?

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

$(function ()   {
var $table = $('table')
    .tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    headerTemplate: '{content}',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_reset: '.reset',
        filter_cssFilter: ['', '', '', 'datepicker']
    }
})
.on('datepicker-apply datepicker-close', function ()  {
    $table.trigger('search');
});
$('.datepicker').dateRangePicker();
});
>  

</script>
```

How do you specificy which column the dateRangePicker can go in?

Comment: It's not as simple as that, you'll need to use the [`filter_formatter` function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html#jquery_ui_datepicker_range_selector) to add the datepicker to the filter row. In the future, I do plan on making it so the filter row can be completely customized to make the process a bit easier.

Comment: How would I add that? I need the datepicker in column 1 that's all instead of (3).  Thank you for commenting

Comment: An example is provided in the link in my last comment.

Comment: It was actually far easier than I thought: `code` filter_cssFilter: ['datepicker', '', '', ''] `code` I simply changed the column there.  Didn't see that